# Left and right recursive parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

This is an evolution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198620/recursive-parser).

I need to parse with megaparsec a data structure like

```
data Foo =
    Simple String
    Dotted Foo String
    Paren String Foo
```

and I would like to parse to it strings like

```
foo ::= alphanum
    | foo "." alphanum
    | alphanum "(" foo ")"
```

For example a the string `"a(b.c).d"` should be parsed to `Dotted (Paren "a" (Dotted (Simple "b") "c")) "d"`.

The problem I have is that this is at the same time left and right recursive.

I have no problems writing the parsers for the first and the third case:

```
parser :: Parser Foo
parser 
    = try (do
        prefix <- alphanum
        constant "("
        content <- parser
        constant ")"
        pure $ Paren prefix content
        )
    <|> Simple alphanum
```

but I'm not able to put together also the parser for the second case. I tried to approach it with `sepBy1` or with `makeExprParser` but I couldn't get it right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To factor out the left recursion in this:

```
foo ::= alphanum
    | foo "." alphanum
    | alphanum "(" foo ")"
```

You can start by rewriting it to this:

```
foo ::= alphanum ("(" foo ")")?
      | foo "." alphanum
```

Then you can factor out the left recursion using the standard trick of replacing:

```
x ::= x y | z
```

With:

```
x ::= z x'

x' ::= y x' | ∅
```

In other words:

```
x ::= z y*
```

With `x` = `foo`, `y` = `"." alphanum`, and `z` = `alphanum ("(" foo ")")?`, that becomes:

```
foo ::= alphanum ("(" foo ")")? ("." alphanum)*
```

Then I believe your parser can just be something like this, since `?` ~ zero or one ~ `Maybe` ~ `optional` and `*` ~ zero or more ~ `[]` ~ `many`:

```
parser = do
  prefix <- Simple <$> alphanum
  maybeParens <- optional (constant "(" *> parser <* constant ")")
  suffixes <- many (constant "." *> alphanum)
  let
    prefix' = case maybeParens of
      Just content -> Paren prefix content
      Nothing -> prefix
  pure $ foldl' Dotted prefix' suffixes
```